# No console application in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I know this might sound *extremely* dumb, but I can't  find the console application template in visual studio 2015. When installed I clicked on custom and selected everything so I wouldn't have to go through the hassle of adding files later on so of course I have visual c++ installed. But for some reason there's no console application template.

Any ideas?
I'm using the community edition.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's located under *Templates->Visual C++->Win32->Win32 Console Application*.

If you cannot find it there, it probably means you did not install the Windows SDK. Go to the *Control Panel->Programs and Features*, select *Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015*, right click on it and select *Change*.

The SDK is hidden quite well in the list of installable features. You can find it under *Windows and Web Development->Universal Windows App Development Tools*. Make sure the *Windows 10 SDK* is selected. By default it's not and I tend to forget to check it when installing VS2015 because it's so damn well hidden.

Answer (score 27):

SOLVED !!!
it is generally with windows 10 or xp 
so when you go to visual c++ there is option of install windows support for ...
and let it download 
bingo!!
next time you can see it there

install these two

[image]

after installation

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem. This is the way of show before i fix it.
[image: with error]

then check you have proper internet connection. net double click and install both. now you can create c++ project.
This is new appearance..[image: After solve problem]

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Unable to download using VS2015 installer. Even when set to download from internet it will fail

Better download winsdksetup.exe at https://developer.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/

Comment: even using winsdksetup.exe at https://developer.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/ then vs got corrupted, reinstalled, tried to update but it never updates, missing file, and internet give no update. Ms sucks, they force this in order for us develioper update the dev languages